# Make the background image in DIV responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my background image to become responsive inside a div. It has a parallax effect when scrolled. I already tried to customize the background in the `media queries` but no hope it only adjust the height and doesn't contain the whole page when in mobile devices width. Can someone give me a clue to solve this? Im new to html and css.

html code for div:

```
<div class="parallax"></div>
```

css code:

```
.parallax { 
    height: 502px;
    background-image: url(../img/back2.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: -70px 80px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 270px) and (max-width: 320px){ 
.parallax { 
    max-height: 300px;
    background-image: url(../img/back2.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: -70px 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use property: `background-size:100% auto;`

If the width property is set to 100%, the image will be responsive and scale up and down.

please see this link for more info: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp)